# Hide/Replace labels with foreach

Tags: psfrag, pgffor

I am trying to make a command that will take a list of labels and use `psfrag` to hide them. in my figure X3 is removed but X1, X2 and X7 are still there.

[OneDrive link to EPS file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aqq57vZVPkGTmdZsiiSwoYphnlqqFg?e=NhUCIs)

Is there something special i need to do to use the foreach `\thing` counter in the `\HideLabel` command

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[runs=2,crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}

\newcommand{\HideLabel}[1]{\foreach \thing in {#1} {%
        \psfrag{\thing}{}}
}


\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[ht!]
        \centering
        \HideLabel{X1,X2,X7}
        \psfrag{X3}{}
        \includegraphics[scale=1]{Figure}
        \caption{Figure caption}
        \label{Figure1}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `\psfrag` works within the scope of the environment in which the `\psfrag` command is used. With `\foreach` a new scope is created for every item in the list, therefore the `\psfrag` commands do not reach the `\includegraphics` call (because the scope of the foreach items has already ended when `\includegraphics` is executed).

As an alternative you can use the list processing functionality of the `etoolbox` package, which does not create a new scope.

MWE (I made a small graph with seven labels, because I didn't want to download a file from an unknown location):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[runs=2,crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\HideLabel}[1]{%
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\psfrag{##1}{}}%
\docsvlist{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{replacelabels}
        \caption{Original figure}
        \label{Figure1}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
        \centering
        \HideLabel{X1,X2,X7}
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{replacelabels}
        \caption{Hidden labels}
        \label{Figure2}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: +1 Well done, I came to the same conclusion because the manual says `A \psfrag command will remain in effect until its surrounding environment is exited. Therefore, you can define global \psfrags which will apply to every figure, or define \psfrags inside a a figure environment (for example) which apply to a single EPS file.` But I didn't find a way to make psfrag global.

Comment: @AndréC It just means use  \psfrag outside of a group (typically in the document preamble)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I am getting an error saying "Command `\do undefined."

Comment: I do notice that it does still seem to work...

Comment: @Phildgg that error is strange, because the `\do` command is defined by `\usepackage{etoolbox}`. Do you get the error also when you run the example _exactly_ as I posted here without any modifications (except for the filename of your image of course)?

Comment: Each time `\HideLabel` is called it shows a message in the log, but the document still compiles and the code still seems to give the desired result. I am using the code as it is posted without modification.